# How to write an if statement with multiple || and && in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, multiple-conditions

What is a concise way to write an if statement with more than many || and && in C?

I want to only execute a printf statement if a either 1,2,4 or 6 AND b = 8 and c = 10, can I put all these conditions into the same if statement?

eg. can I write something like:

```
if ((a = 1||2||4||6) && b == 8 && c == 10)

//do something
```

This doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if ((a == 1 || a == 2 || a == 4 || a == 6) && b == 8 && c == 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

It might be better to write this with a `switch` statement inside of an `if` instead.

```
if(b == 8 && c == 10) {
    switch(a) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 4:
        case 6:
            printf("value works\n");
    }
}
```